# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n, vue-composition-api

The following code works flawless:

```js
// validation-rules.ts
export const requiredRule = (val: string) => !!val || 'Field is required'
```

Usage:

```js
import { requiredRule } from 'src/components/application-form/shared/validation-rules'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const answerInputValidationRules = computed(() => {
        return [requiredRule]
    })
    return { answerInputValidationRules }
  },
})
```

When we try to add the translation key by using the package [vue-i18n-composable](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-composable) it fails with the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined"

What we've tried so far:

```js
// validation-rules.ts
import { computed, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n-composable'

const { t } = useI18n()

export const requiredRule = (val: string) =>
  !!val || ref(t('validationRules.requiredField')) // fail

export const requiredRule = (val: string) =>
  !!val || computed(() => t('validationRules.requiredField')) // fail

export const requiredRule = (val: string) =>
  !!val || t('validationRules.requiredField') // fail
```

Translation within the `setup()` method work flawless too.

```js
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n-composable'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n()
    
    const driverRule = (val: string) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(`${t('validationRules.requiredField')}`)
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
```

What are we missing here? How can we have just one file containing all the logic for these rules and use them through out the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I didn't understand it completely. This fixed it for me:

```js
// useValidationRules.ts
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n-composable'

export const useValidationRules = () => {
  const { t } = useI18n()

  const requiredRule = (val: string) =>
    !!val || t('validationRules.requiredField')

  return { requiredRule }
}
```

Usage:

```js
import { useValidationRules } from 'src/composables/useValidationRules'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { requiredRule } = useValidationRules()

    const answerInputValidationRules = computed(() => {
        return [requiredRule]
    })
    return { answerInputValidationRules }
  },
})
```